# I don't know where to define removeFromSuperview () for memory leak countermeasures when implementing addSubview with viewDidLoad

Tags: swift

Although self.view.addSubview (webView) is implemented in viewDidLoad, memory leak occurs because addSubview is performed to display Viewcontroller. So, I am considering removing memory leak by adding removeFromeSuperview (), but because the screen transitions by Sidemenu, the viewcontroller is circulated, and it is not possible to implement such as deleting the viewcontroller when it transitions. Is there any way?
I put the code for reference.

```
import UIKit
import SideMenu
import WebKit

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationBarDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    let homeUrl = "https://www.apple.com/"
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let processPool = WKProcessPool()
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        navigationBar.delegate = self


        configuration.processPool = processPool
        self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 85, width:self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height-85), configuration: configuration)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
        openUrl(urlString: homeUrl)
        self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    }

    func openUrl(urlString: String) {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.webView.load(urlRequest)
        print("open")
    } 
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turned out that "viewWillDisappear" and "viewDidDisappear" cannot be used in the sidemenu, so I gave up the sidemenu and solved it by using the basic Navigationmenu.